# Are my chinese characters readable?

Tags: handwriting

I am trying to write a cute card for my Chinese girlfriend. But I speak no Chinese. Can you read what I wrote below? Is my handwriting OK?

[image]

Comment: use Google Translate, input "happy New year, I love you" and set translate to Chinese,  you will get the characters you wanted "新年快乐，我爱你"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your characters are very readable, but I think you wrote the wrong first character. Looks like you meant to write 新 but you only wrote 亲 (the left side of 新). 亲 is like "beloved" or "dear", but 新 is "new" (as in "New year").

Even still, it's quite obvious what you meant.

---

EDIT: I had originally made the comment that:

"You also forgot 2 strokes on 愛 if you were meaning to write the traditional form or you have a 2 extra strokes if you were meaning the simplified form (爱)."

However, droooze pointed out in the comments that the "extra strokes" are just the left and right pieces of 冖. The fact that they are quite disconnected from the 一 is what had me confused.

Comment: `2 extra strokes if you were meaning the simplified form (爱)` could you point the two extra strokes out? If you're talking about the two small marks on either side, I think the OP was trying to draw the「冖」part. Don't confuse「爱」with「爰」, they're two different characters.

Comment: @droooze Now that you point it out, I think you're definitely right. I had just assumed those middle dots were part of the 心, but they are, as you said, mostly likely part of the 冖. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely readable! Why did you ask? You did a good job. First character is wrong though. It should be 新 (xin) not 亲 (qin). 新means “new”， 亲means “my dear” or “Love” “babe” or .... many many other meanings but “new”. People will understand it, just a bit fanny.  Your handwriting is absolutely readable.